# How to store nth column of comma delimited file in an array?

Tags: c++, arrays, string, token, delimiter

I have a file which stores data in the following format (this is just a small sample) :

```
AD,Andorra,AN,AD,AND,20.00,Andorra la Vella,Europe,Euro,EUR,67627.00
AE,United Arab Emirates,AE,AE,ARE,784.00,Abu Dhabi,Middle East,UAE Dirham,AED,2407460.00
AF,Afghanistan,AF,AF,AFG,4.00,Kabul,Asia,Afghani,AFA,26813057.00
AG,Antigua and Barbuda,AC,AG,ATG,28.00,Saint John's,Central America and the Caribbean,East Caribbean Dollar,XCD,66970.00
AI,Anguilla,AV,AI,AIA,660.00,The Valley,Central America and the Caribbean,East Caribbean Dollar,XCD,12132.00
```

I want to store the second field of each line such that my array contains only the country names like so:

```
string countryArray[] = {"Andorra,United Arab Emirates", "Afghanistan", "Antigua and Barbuda", "Anguilla"}
```

But each time I run my code, a segmentation fault occurs. Here is my code :

```
countryArray[256];

if (myfile)
{
        while (getline(myfile,line))
        {
            std::string s = line;
            std::string delimiter = ",";

            size_t pos = 0;
            std::string token;
            short loop=0;

            while ((pos = s.find(delimiter)) != std::string::npos) 
            {
                  token = s.substr(0, pos);
                  s.erase(0, pos + delimiter.length());  

                  if (loop < 2)
                  {
                       loop++;
                  }
                  else
                  {
                       loop+=11;
                       countryArray[count] = token;
                       count++;
                  }

             }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider using `std::istringstream`. Something like:

```
while(getline(myfile, line))
{
    std::istringstream iss(line);

    std::string data;
    getline(iss, data, ','); // get first column into data
    getline(iss, data, ','); // get second column into data

    countryArray[count] = data;
    ++count;
}
```

What `std::istringstream` does is allow you to treat a `std::string` like an input stream just like a regular file.

The you can use `getline(iss, data, ',')` which reads from the stream up to the next comma ',' and stores it in `std::string data`.

**EDIT:**

Also consider using `std::vector` rather than an array.

Comment: Thanks! +1 for simple and elegant solution :)

Answer (score 2):

Your segfault is most likely the result of not initializing `count`, and then using that variable as the index into the `countryArray` array. Thus you could be easily overrunning the bounds of the array since the value in `count` is undefined.